How to fix: "headers were not signed" in uploadFeed?
I'm developing a private application using the sp-api from Amazon.
And I want to create a Listing service to sell my used book so I'm using the Feeds API.
I always use the x-amz-token for the moment. I fetch it in my middleware and send in it to amazon in the request header and it always worked.
Even for createFeedDocument: without it, it doesn't work. With it everything is good.
But once i do the uploadFeed request i keep getting an error :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message>                         <HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-access-token</HeadersNotSigned>
<RequestId></RequestId>
<HostId></HostId>
</Error>

And when I check on the documentation for uploadFeed or in the useCase for Feed (v2021) I dont find anything about it.
I watch this video from Amazon Seller University too and in the doc they talk about selfAuthorized in the developer panel. Is it what I need to do here ? Or do I need more something else to fix the error ?

OK so I found the answer,
My problem was: I didn't need AUTH for this request unlike the others.
Here is the code I used:
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
};
const feed = builderFeed();
const response = await axios.put(document.url, Buffer.from(feed), {
    headers,
});

And with this it's working.

99% it has to do with how you are constructing the Canonical Request in order to generate the Authorization header.
If you are not using an official SDK, in order to generate it, you must strictly follow rules explained in this article written by me.
As you can see the Authorization header is an hash of a particular string which contains a lot of stuff besides the HTTP headers.
I suggest you to test it by using Postman as written in this article (also written by me) or on this on the official Amazon SP-API docs.

Ty for your answer. But there is a problem with your article, there is not such thing as "Policy that allows members to “Invoke” the “Execute API” service." The only available options are "AWS service", "AWS account", "Web identity", "SAML 2.0 federation", "Custom trust policy" and the last one seems to only let you add actions for STS but it's what you do in the next step so I dont think it's that.

Did you try with Postman first?

I tried with the Postman article you did, where there is not such line as "Policy that allows members to “Invoke” the “Execute API” service." but I keep getting stuck to the Step 3 — Assume role. I get a response Sender InvalidClientTokenId The security token included in the request is invalid. even if I changed 3 times the access keys of my User on aws, changed the RoleSessionName, added the authorization and all my environment variables working (I can see them when hovering).
